# VSE Motion Blur?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, masking

So I'm editing a video with someone jumping really high, and I've masked them out, animated them, and it looks fine, except for the motion blur. The person I've masked out is way too crisp!
[image: Masked out]
Is there any way to use Blender's motion blur settings with the vse editor?
I really don't want to use the blur effect, as it really doesn't provide the best results

Comment: i don't use the VSE but i think you should be looking for a smooth mask instead

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/fake-motion-blur-on-video-footage-using-compositor

Comment: I think this is possible in the compositor, but I'm not sure about the VSE.. See http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor#Compositing_Node

Comment: Okay, looking into it...

Comment: There are some VSE to Compositor solutions, try to google them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non linear editors are generally not used for compositing for a number of reasons. NLEs have very thin margins for performance, while compositing may require hundreds to thousands of operations to craft a desired output. In industrial imaging, these two processes are isolated and divided for this very reason.

While you might not be doing post production on a feature length film, there is much to be gained by following the patterns that such projects follow.

1. Cut your project into the shots and timing you require using an NLE. Once you are happy with the pacing and the edit, your edit is "Picture Locked." You now know precisely which frames you are going to be performing deeper surgery on and what elements you require.
2. Take your work into the compositor and perform the surgery. You gain the added quality of compositing on 32 bit float imagery as well as avoiding other not-so-obvious compositing problems such as nonlinear color blending. Specifically regarding your work, you can find various tools to help you regarding motion blurring. See [Motion Blur option in the mask node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor).
3. Repeat for each shot required. At the end of the process, output your still frames and encode to a final motion picture format if needed.

Comment: Wow, thats really quite amazing! I am definetly going to try this workflow out. Thanks for the great support!

Comment: @DragonHeart While alien at first, an offline to online process will almost certainly elevate your work. It forces you to focus on particular regions of production at the proper moments. Editing during editing. Effects during effects. Grading during grading. Etc. By allocating time and energy to discrete phases, you waste less time twiddling elements that have no place. As no surprise, this pipeline has been used for nearly a century of motion picture imaging.