# Trick to get motion blur to work on grease objects?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I have a circle object made with Grease pencil (circle with black fill) and a simple sphere mesh
[image]

If I make a simple animation, moving each circle/sphere out to the side and enable motion blur I get:
[image]

Motion blur is not applied to the grease object.

Can we do any trick to enable this?

Comment: The only trick I know is wait for the BF to implement it.

Comment: Do you know of any progress on this? is it even on the plan?

Comment: I know there are at least two feature requests on RCS: [Grease pencil motion blur ⁠— Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/l77j/) and [Motion Blur for GreasePencil Line Art Modifier using Grease Pencil Visual Effects ⁠— Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/08M3/t). As for the BF, it doesn't seem to have plans for it yet: [Grease Pencil Project - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/projects/6)

Comment: Also in the meantime you can fake the motion blur using the Grease Pencil's blur modifier

Comment: This sounds like one of the workaround https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/11044/2214 ... or there was an addon for 2.79 VSE that generated strip group with several strips with low opacity and frame offset per strip to Overlay strips before and after current frame (softer blur means more strips) ... but it would be faster generate m-blur out of blender in some video editor app.

Comment: Or here is another post-production that I didn't check closer, but it seems he is using before / after onset strips to generate difference in frames and use this result as a mask for blurred strip ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Avj4KgUL6yQ ... but like before - blender cant do it for now, so it is based on video post production, so other apps can handle it more easier.

Comment: Some years ago when Eevee didn't have embedded object motion blur I wrote add-on which solves this. It works much slower than original render because it has to render each subframe individually and then mix them into one frame. It supports motion blur on each render pass. It is free, so I don't think this can be considered an attempt of advertising it. Probably it could be a solution - https://github.com/sorecords/true_motion_blur